# Looking for a faster way to change all values in a column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a csv file that contains data from captured network packets, including the column src_ip which stores the source IP and port numbers in the format 192.168.1.1:1234. I'm currently using the following code to split the IP and port and only save the IP:

```
pkt_data = pd.read_csv("sample_packets.csv", parse_dates=["Time"]).set_index("Time").sort_index()
for index_label, row_series in pkt_data.iterrows():
    pkt_data.at[index_label, "src_ip"] = row_series["src_ip].split(':')[0]
```

The problem is that my data set is about 200k rows and this code takes close to a minute to finish.
Is there a faster / better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
pkt_data["src_ip"] = pkt_data["src_ip"].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0])
```

Comment: here's a very similar solution with a little syntactic sugar: `pkt_data["src_ip"] = pkt_data["src_ip"].str.split(':')[0]`

Comment: @Robert when I tried your solution I get an error saying the size of the data doesn't match the size of the index.

Comment: Adrian, can you share a simple repeatable example? and I can take a look